# Creating a clear function for budgeting app

Tags: reactjs, function

I am working on creating a clear button that once clicked will clear all the transactions that have been added to the transaction list with localStorage.  My button works but its buggy, once it gets clicked I get the following error about a separate function I have to get the balance. If I refresh the page afterwords though all the transactions will be cleared.

The error I am receiving ...

```
TypeError: amounts.reduce(...).toFixed is not a function
```

my component

```
import react, {useState, useEffect} from 'react'
import Transaction from './Transaction'


const Form = () => {

//initial state
const [transaction, setTransaction] = useState({
    description: '',
    amount: ''
  })
  const [list, setList] = useState(
    JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('list')) || []
  )
  const [balance, setBalance] = useState('')
  const [income, setIncome] = useState(
    JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('income'))
  )
  const [expense, setExpense] = useState(JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('expense')))

    //updates based onChange value
const updateBalance = (e) => {
    setTransaction({
        ...transaction,
        [e.target.name]:
         e.target.type == 'number' ? parseInt(e.target.value) : e.target.value
        })
}

//identify if transaction is income/expense

const plusMinus = () => {
    transaction.amount > 0
     ? setIncome(income + transaction.amount)
      : setExpense(expense + transaction.amount)
}
// updates balance after transaction is added

const getBalance = () => {
    const amounts = list.map(i => i.amount);
    const money = amounts.reduce((acc, item) => (acc += item), 0).toFixed(2);
    setBalance(money)
  }
  
useEffect(() => {
    getBalance()
    localStorage.setItem('list', JSON.stringify(list))
    localStorage.setItem('income', JSON.stringify(income))
    localStorage.setItem('expense', JSON.stringify(expense))
  }, [list])


//clear transaction list
const clearBudget = () => {
    localStorage.clear();
}

const onSubmit = e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    setList([transaction, ...list])
    plusMinus()
    setTransaction({ description: '', amount: ''})
    }

return (
    
    <div>
        <div className='totals'>
        <h2 className='balance'> Current Balance </h2>
        <h3> ${balance} </h3>
            <h4> Income: ${income} Expense: ${expense} </h4>
        </div>
        < br />
        < br />
        < br />
         <h2 className='trans-history'> Transaction History </h2>
           {list.map(i => {
               return (
                   <div className='trans'>
                       <ul  key={i.description}>
                    {i.description} ${parseInt(i.amount)}
                   </ul>
                   </div>
               )
           })}
           <br />
           <br />
        <h2 className='enter-item'> Enter an Item </h2>
        <form onSubmit={onSubmit}>
       <div> 
           <input 
           type='text' 
           className="input-trans" 
           placeholder='Enter Transaction'
           value={Transaction.description}
           name='description'
           onChange={updateBalance}
           >
           </input>
        </div> 
        <div>
        <input 
        type='number'
         className='input-trans' 
         placeholder='Enter Amount'
         name='amount'
         value={transaction.amount}
         onChange={updateBalance}
         >
        </input>
        </div>
        <br/>
        <div className='button-container'>
            <button type='submit' className='button is-primary'> Submit </button>
            <button className='button is-danger' onClick={clearBudget}> Clear </button>
        </div>
    </form>
    </div>
 )
}

export default Form
```

Comment: What is your value of `list` in `getBalance()`?

Comment: I updated my question to show my component.

Comment: Thanks Gabe! Any chance you can throw this into a Code Sandbox or CodePen so we can poke at it some more?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like `amounts.reduce` is returning something that is not a number. You could check the type before to perform `toFixed` function.

E.g.:

```js
const amounts = list.map((i) => i.amount).map(Number);
const money = amounts.reduce((acc, item) => (acc += item), 0)
if (typeof money === 'number') {
  setBalance(money.toFixed(2))
} else {
  setBalance(money)
}
```

Comment: I attempted to this, however when I try to clear it just populates NaN instead of removing the transactions.

Comment: That´s mean that you reduce method is returning `Not a Number`, I would suggest to check the type of item, maybe it's actually a string a not a number, if it's like that, I would update my answer

Comment: yeah so how its set right now is a string, I updated all my code in my original question.

Comment: Check my updated answer, you can use a map to parse all the amount to a number and if it's because it was an string, I would remove the type checking

Comment: Thanks for your continued help, but even with the updated answer im still having issues, still coming up as NaN when I clear the transactions.